# Connection from Remote Desktop WIN10 to work station UBUNTU20.04

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop, xrdp

I would like to connect to a work station with Ubuntu 20.04 (private ip) using the remote desktop present in win10. I tested meny tutorial present in internet, without success. I would like ask: there are some parameters in the work station that I can check to solve my problem? The steps that I implemented are:

1. Verify thet ubuntu-desktop is present
2. Install xrdp
3. Verify the demon running with "sudo systemctl status xrdp"
4. sudo adduser xrdp ssl-cert
5. Allow port 3389 with "sudo ufw from xx.yy.xx.ww to any port 3389
6. Try to connect using the remote desktop of Win10

TIA

Comment: Please confirm you ran `sudo ufw allow from [...]`, and not `sudo ufw from`? What error are you getting?

Comment: Yes, I make a mistake. The command is: "sudo ufw allow from zzz.yyy.zzz.www to any port 3389". No error. I'm not able to establish a connection between remote-desktop on win10 and the work-station